# Display choosen image instead of default image first time user adds image cell in collectionview Swift 5

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to iOS development and coding on swift 5. I have a collection view that the user can add images to. There are two issues. First, I would like to not display any cells when the user first views the collection view. The second issue is that when the user adds the first image, it displays the default image/cell and not the selected image from image picker.

I have searched for this answer but haven't found anything to help resolve my issue. Thank you

I added minus 1 to numberOfItemsInSection function. When I run this it shows no cells in the collection view. But when I add an image/cell, the default image/cells appears and not the image the user chooses from photo library.

```swift
// collectionviewcell
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

    var delegate: CollectionProtocol?
    var index: IndexPath?

    @IBOutlet weak var deleteBtn: UIButton!
    @IBAction func deleteBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.deleteData(indx: (index?.row)!)
        print("photo deleted")
    }
}


// view controller
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imgArr.count - 1
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the image to `imgArr` and reloading the `collectionView` when the image is selected?

Comment: I have this:
      func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            
            imgArr.append(image)
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Answer (score 0):

I needed to initialize the imageArray with an empty state. 
So I updated it to:
let imageArray = UIImage

Also updated func numberOfItemsInSection to return numberOfRowsInSection